# All my objects change in my arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm adding a new object(class) to an `ArrayList`, but when I try to get variables from the objects in my `ArrayList`, the variables are the same in all my classes. I've added a NEW object, so I expect it to add a new object, right?

This is my code in my for loop. The print says that every variable in the object[i] has the same number.

```
ArrayList treeDots;
ArrayList branchList;
boolean clicked; 

void setup ()
{
    size(1024, 768, P3D);
    clicked = false;
    treeDots = new ArrayList();
    branchList = new ArrayList();
    treeDots.add(new TreeDot(width/2, height/2));
}

void draw ()
{
    if (clicked)
        AddTreeDot();

    if (treeDots.size() > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < treeDots.size() -1 ; i++)
        {
            int temp_loc = 0;
            TreeDot index1 = (TreeDot)treeDots.get(i);
            TreeDot index2 = (TreeDot)treeDots.get(i + 1);
            print(index1.xLoc(temp_loc)  + " ");
            print(i + " ");
            print(index2.xLoc(temp_loc)  + " ");
            print(i + " ");
            strokeWeight(2);
            stroke(#09FF00);
            line(index1.xLoc(temp_loc),index1.yLoc(temp_loc), index2.xLoc(temp_loc), index2.yLoc(temp_loc));
        }
    }
}

void AddTreeDot ()
{
    int randomX = 0;
    int randomY = 0;
    treeDots.add(new TreeDot(randomDotX(randomX), randomDotY(randomY)));
    clicked = false;
}

int randomDotX (int _randomX)
{
    TreeDot temp = (TreeDot) treeDots.get(treeDots.size() -1);
    int temp_x_loc = 0;
    int lastDotX = temp.xLoc(temp_x_loc);
    _randomX = lastDotX + int(random(-10, 10));
    return _randomX;
}

int randomDotY (int _randomY)
{
    TreeDot temp = (TreeDot) treeDots.get(treeDots.size() -1);
    int temp_y_loc = 0;
    int lastDotY = temp.yLoc(temp_y_loc);
    _randomY = lastDotY + int(random(0, 10));
    return _randomY;
}

void mouseClicked ()
{
    clicked = true;
}
```

and here is my class code

```
int randomSpread;
boolean canIGrow;
boolean endDot;
int x_loc;
int y_loc;
int lineThickness;

class TreeDot
{
    TreeDot (int x_loc_par, int y_loc_par)
    {
        x_loc = x_loc_par;
        y_loc = y_loc_par;
        //ellipse(x_loc_par, y_loc_par, 10, 10);
        endDot = false; 
    }

    int xLoc (int _x_loc)
    {
        _x_loc = x_loc;
        return _x_loc;
    }

    int yLoc(int _y_loc)
    {
        _y_loc = y_loc;
        return _y_loc;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the weird part? What are you expecting?

Comment: In my for loop I check for the variables in the objects in the array and if the code works correctly index1.xLoc(temp_loc) should have a diffrent value then index2.xLoc(temp_loc)

Comment: Your variable declarations in your class code should be inside your `class TreeDot {.....}` definition. Give it a try. Also, your for loop is creating tempLoc=0; everytime it iterates. Do you want that?

Comment: @MikeOttink      which one worked? :)

Comment: Putting the variables inside my class worked! Sorry for the insanely late response -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have to declare variable inside the class & this code will be prblematic.

```
int xLoc(int _x_loc)
{
    _x_loc = x_loc;
    return _x_loc;
}

int yLoc(int _y_loc)
{
    _y_loc = y_loc;
    return _y_loc;
}
```

Then in call it

```
int temp_loc = 0;
TreeDot index1 = (TreeDot)treeDots.get(i);
TreeDot index2 = (TreeDot)treeDots.get(i + 1);
print(index1.xLoc(temp_loc)  + " ");
print(i + " ");
print(index2.xLoc(temp_loc)  + " ");
print(i + " ");
```

This line `index1.xLoc(temp_loc)` reset the value for you to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your TreeDot getters/setters are messed up. In `xLoc()` you are passing in `_x_loc`, making it equal to `x_loc` and return it. Same for `yLoc()`

Answer (score 1):

Class variables should be declared inside the class.
What you're doing is you're setting the same (global) variables each time you add a new TreeDot.

P.S. your getters are not the problem as some of the answers are mentioning.